# Different color for each tab

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I have some tabs on my page using the following HTML. Currently the tabs are of the same color. I want each tab to be of a different color when clicked.

I am a Technical Writer and hence don't have much information about coding. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#" name="tab1">'Architecture'</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab2">'Business System Functionality'</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab3">'Environment Administration'</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Product'</a></li>    
<li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Testing'</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Training'</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Site Management'</a></li>
<li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Release Notes'</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also have the following css

```
  #tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  }

  #tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
  }

  #tabs a {
  position: relative;
  background: #3399cc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
  padding: .7em 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  }

 #tabs a:hover,
 #tabs a:hover::after,
 #tabs a:focus,
 #tabs a:focus::after {
 background: #fff;
 }

 #tabs a:focus {
 outline: 0;
 }

 #tabs a::after {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 right: -.5em;  
 bottom: 0;
 width: 1em;
 background: #ddd;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 transform: skew(10deg);
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;  
 }

 #tabs #current a,
 #tabs #current a::after {
  background: #fff;
 z-index: 3;
}
```

And the following JQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
  $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate the first tab
  $("#content #tab1").fadeIn(); // Show first tab's content

  $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current") { //detection for 
      current tab
      return;
    } else {
      $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
      $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
      $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
      $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for the   
      current tab
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3vbfq3bf/

Comment: you can add some custom attribute to every element in a list, and then on click read this att value and set it with css() function..

Comment: you can add manually background color to every li by giving different classes to each li

Comment: @Luka, I am not aware how to do it. Can you please guide? I am not a developer, hence facing issues :(

Comment: @Sagar, Can you show it to me for two tabs. Then i can do it myself.

Comment: @Sagar....Can you look at this question...Gmail has been blocked in our office..hence not able to ping you there....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972547/break-a-ul-in-columns-edited-for-clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** added for first three `li`

You want this? added only two `li` so manually you can give classes to each li and write respective css for it.

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
$("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate the first tab
$("#content #tab1").fadeIn(); // Show first tab's content

$('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for 
    current tab
     return;       
    }
    else{             
      $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
      $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
      $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
      $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for the   
      current tab
      }
      });
      });
      </script>
```

```css
 #tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
}

#tabs a {
  position: relative;
  background: #3399cc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
  padding: .7em 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#tabs a:hover,
#tabs a:hover::after,
#tabs a:focus,
#tabs a:focus::after {
  background: #fff;
}
#tabs a.one:hover,
#tabs a.one:hover::after,
#tabs a.one:focus,
#tabs a.one:focus::after {
  background: red;
}
#tabs a.second:hover,
#tabs a.second:hover::after,
#tabs a.second:focus,
#tabs a.second:focus::after {
  background: blue;
}
#tabs a.third:hover,
#tabs a.third:hover::after,
#tabs a.third:focus,
#tabs a.third:focus::after {
  background: green;
}


#tabs a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#tabs a::after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: -.5em;  
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  transform: skew(10deg);
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;  
}

#tabs #current a,
#tabs #current a::after {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

#content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a class="one" href="#" name="tab1">'Architecture'</a></li>
    <li><a class="second" href="#" name="tab2">'Business System Functionality'</a></li>
    <li><a class="third" href="#" name="tab3">'Environment Administration'</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Product'</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Testing'</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Training'</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Site Management'</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Release Notes'</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ya..and please make changes all css as per your need.

Comment: @Sagar...Thanks for your help....I want the color to be displayed when the tab is clicked....Right now its displaying the color all the time....Sorry for the trouble...must be something small but I don't have the knowledge to change it

Comment: on tab click?? no problem..wait

Comment: @Sagar...Thanks...let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115108/discussion-between-pankaj-morajkar-and-sagar-kodte).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what You wanted to do?

https://jsfiddle.net/u3nwLodj/

```
  $('#tabs a').on('click', function(e) {

   var color = $(this).attr("data-color");

   $(this).css("background-color", color);

  });
```

> data-color attribute can be also a hex or rgb()

```
    <ul id="tabs">
       <li><a href="#" name="tab1" data-color="white">'Architecture'</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" name="tab2" data-color="blue">'Business System Functionality'</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" name="tab3" data-color="green">'Environment Administration'</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" name="tab4">'Product'</a></li>   
    </ul>
```

Comment: @Luka...let me just try this in real-time and check.

Comment: Hi Luka... its giving the following error...not sure why..."=" expected: /content/body/pre[2], line 2, column 33.....its working in the fiddle but on my end it giving the error....

Comment: I don't know, please check your syntax.

Comment: @Luka...let me check....I am using Dekiscript in the site...Maybe something to do with it...let me verify again

Comment: @Luka....Thanks for your help....Your steps were simpler but for some reason the data-color attribute is not working in Dekiscript....not sure why...I tried hex as well as rgb but still its not working....If i had the option i would have marked your answer correct as well...Thanks again...

Comment: @PankajMorajkar np, still think this is much smarter option but the others will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below approach:

https://jsfiddle.net/3vbfq3bf/8/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
   $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate the first tab
   $("#content #tab1").fadeIn(); // Show first tab's content

   $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current") { //detection for current tab
       return;
     } else {
       $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
       $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
       $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
       $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for the current tab

       $(this).css("background-color",getRandomColor());
     }
   });
 });

 function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: this is ok if he wants a random color.