# Break a UL in Columns (edited for clarity)

Tags: html, css

I have the following code on my page for my first class.

```
<div class="home-tab-title">
<img class="home-duck" src="https://accenturelife-
prod.mindtouch.us/@api/deki/files/2426/AlipSuite.png?origin=mt-web" />
<div class="home-heading">'Training Documentation'</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content1">

<div class="tab-content1-block">
<div class="home-subheading">'Getting Started'</div>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li><a href="/@api/deki/files/2682/ALIP_Overview_Presentation.pptx? 
origin=mt-web">'ALIP Overview'</a></li>
<li><a href="/Training/ASW_VPN_Setup">'ASW VPN Setup'</a></li>
<li><a href="/Training/Workflow_and_Java_Version_8">'Workflow and Java     
Version 8'</a></li>
<li><a href="/Training/Squirrel_Database_Tool_-
_Installation_and_Documentation">'ALIP TS Squirrel Documentation'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Eclipse_Workbench_Installation_Guide">'Eclipse 
Workbench Installation Guide'</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content1-block">
<div class="home-subheading">'Actuarial Analyst Training'</div>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li><a     
href="/03_Training/ALIP_Product_Documentation_and_Training_Outline">'ALIP 
Product Documentation and Training Outline'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Onshore_Training_Approach_-_Actuaries">'Onshore 
Training Approach - Actuaries'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Self-Guided_Product_Training_Agenda">'Self Guided 
Product Training Agenda'</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content1-block">
<div class="home-subheading">'Business Analyst Training'</div>
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li><a href="/03_Training/Overview">'Overview'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Exercises">'Exercises'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Policy_Administration">'Policy Administration'</a>   
</li>
<li><a href="/@api/deki/files/2729/Defect_Management_using_RTC.pptx?
origin=mt-web">'Defect Management'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Database_Training/">'Database Training'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Functional_Specification">'Functional 
Specification'</a></li>
<li><a href="/Training/New_Business_and_Underwriting">'New Business and 
Underwriting'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Business_Configuration_Training">'Business   
Configuration Training'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Product_Configuration_Training">'Product 
Configuration Training'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/ALIP_Functional_Training_Outline">'ALIP Functional 
Training Outline'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Onshore_Training_Approach_-_Business">'Onshore   
Training Approach - Business'</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Have the following css for this class:

```
.home-tab-title {
 width: 100%;
 height: 65px;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 }

 img.home-duck{
 width: 35px;
 float: left;
 padding: 12px 10px 0 0;
 }

 .home-heading {
 display:block;
 float: left;
font-size: 22px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
clear: right;
font-family: "Segoe UI", arial, sans-serif;
}

.home-subheading {
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 }

.home-subheading{
font-size:15px;
color: #000;
font-weight: 500;
font-family: "Segoe UI", arial, sans-serif;;
display: inline-flex;
}

.tab-content1 {
margin-left: 2.2em;
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: left;
min-width: 40px;
}

.tab-content1-block {padding: 0 5em 1em .5em;}
.tab-content1-block ul li {margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:-22px;}
```

The output is displayed as follows:

[image]

I have a second class with a large numbers of ul's. I want to break it into three columns and want them to be aligned exactly below the uls of the first columns.

```
 <div class="tab-content1-block1">
 <div class="home-subheading">'Business Configurator Training'</div>
 <ul style="list-style: none;">
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3170/BC_Exercise.zip?origin=mt-web">'BC   
 Exercise'</a></li>
 <li><a href="/03_Training/ALIP_Configuration_Tips">'ALIP Configuration 
 Tips'</a></li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3161/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
 _Introduction.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Introduction'</a>  
 </li>
<li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3159/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
 _Common_Admin.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Common Admin'</a>    
</li>
<li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3160/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_- 
_Forms.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Forms'</a></li>
<li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3162/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
_Lookup.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Lookup'</a></li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3165/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
 _Rules.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Rules'</a></li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3169/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
 _Workflow.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Workflow'</a></li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3163/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
 _Page_Group_Views.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Page Group   
 Views'</a></li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3164/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-  
 _Page_Groups.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Page Groups'</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3166/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
 _Schema_Mgmt.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Schema Mgmt'</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3167/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_- 
 _Skills_Check.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Skills Check'</a> 
 </li>
 <li><a href="/@api/deki/files/3168/Understanding_ALIP_Business_Config_-
 _Tabbed_Workflow.pptx?origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Config - Tabbed 
 Workflow'</a></li>
 <li><a 
 href="/@api/deki/files/3158/ALIP_Business_Configuration_Training_2008.ppt?  
 origin=mt-web">'ALIP Business Configuration Training 2008'</a></li>
 <li><a  

 href="/03_Training/ALIP_Functional_and_Business_Configuration_
 Training_Outline">
'ALIP Functional and Business Configuration Training Outline'</a></li>
<li><a href="/03_Training/Onshore_Training_Approach_-_Business">'Onshore   
 Training Approach - Business Configurator'</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS code for this class is as follows

```
 .tab-content1-block1 {padding: 0 5em 1em 5em;}
 .tab-content1-block1 ul li {margin-bottom:10px; margin-left:-22px;}

 .tab-content1-block1 ul 
 {
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-gap: 20px;
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
  }
```

The output is as follows.The alignment doesn't seem to be proper. It should be exactly below the columns in the first figure.
[image]

Can somebody help to fix this?Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Why it even should be? Why not use normal `table` instead? make ul as table possible with `display` attribute as `table` and `table-cell` and using child-parent selectors `parent>child { style:stye;}`

Comment: @Sugar...sorry I don't understand...I am not from a development background....Can you please explain?

Comment: why do you want to use list element (`ul`, `ol`,`li`) when it's actually require table elements (`table`,`tr`,`td`)? In css there's a `display` property with possible `table` and `table-cell` variations. @memo offers you to use `flex` for "rubber" markup. i'm not really familiar with it, so probably you should use his variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated my pen to match your screenshot: http://codepen.io/memoblue/pen/XKGXAN

Here you go:

```
.tab-content1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  > div:not(.tab-content1-block1) {
    flex-basis: 33.3333%;
  }
}

.tab-content1-block1 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    > li {
      flex-basis: 33.3333%;
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** it's using SCSS and I didn't add the browser prefixes to keep it easier to read… Let me know if anything's unclear.